# Set a Parent property on Child Objects when binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, defaultmodelbinder

We have a hierarchical model of the shape ([yuml-ized](http://yuml.me/edit/4bcc58e0)):

[image: [Order] 1 Parent - Items 0..* [LineItem]]

And a controller action that takes an `Order`-typed parameter:

```
public ActionResult UpdateOrder(Order order)
{
    ...
}
```

With the posted form having fields for the line items, too, we get a tree of objects from the MVC's model binding where as the binders create a new order object for each order to be bound.

**The question:** Is it possible to have the binding mechanism set the `Parent` property of each `LineItem` to the `Order` object they are being added too?

---

I take it that the binder that binds the `Order` object is responsible for executing a binder for each child object, too, by calling `BindModel` on the child object binders. We already have custom implementations (inheriting from `DefaultModelBinder`) in place: A `OrderBinder` as well as a `LineItem` binder.

How can our `LineItem.BindModel` method find out whether the `LineItem` being bound is "stand-alone" or about to be added to an `Order` whose binding is in progress, and if the latter is the case, how do we get the reference to that `Order`?